# jQuery click div outside should hide the div, the child divs on click should not hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML markup like this

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-container">
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want that when mouse is clicked on the outside of content-wrap div then the content-wrap div should be hide. Here in my markup you can see I have just used two divs called outside and wrapper before content-wrap. But in real I have many divs before content-wrap. If any child divs of content-wrap has been clicked then the div should not be hide. So can someone tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.
Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/f2p23vsq/)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: you could have a look at Ben Almans 'outside events' plugin too: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You can call `stopPropagation()` on `.content-wrap`'s click event to prevent the action from bubbling:

```
$('div.content-wrap').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
});

$("body").click(function(){
   $(".content-wrap").fadeOut(); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2p23vsq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just select the content class and hide that?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.content').click(function() {
        $( ".content" ).hide( "slow", function() {
            alert( "Animation complete." );
          });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS Code:**

Duplicate click function is due to the fact that `.parents()` filter parameter allows for only one CSS selector.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.content-wrap').parents('.outside').click(function(){
        $(this).find('div.content-wrap').hide();
    }).end().parents('.wrapper').click(function(){
        $(this).children('div.content-wrap').hide();
    });        
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/f2p23vsq/14/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide text using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("html").click(function () {
        jQuery(".content-wrap").fadeOut();
    });
    $(".content-wrap").click(function () {
        alert("click");
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2p23vsq/15/)